# вывод конкретных категорий wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, cms

Сайт работает на Wordpress.
Есть код

```
<div class="books_content">
    <?php 

    query_posts('cat=10, cat=16'); 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    ?>

    <div class="book">
    <div class="previev">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="book_tag">
    <?php the_tags('', ' > '); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="book_description">
    <div class="post_cat">
    <?php the_category('', 'single'); ?>
    </div>

    <a class="book_title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>   
    </a>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile ?>   
    </div>
```

Нужно передать сюда

`query_posts('cat=10, cat=16');`

значение двух разных js-переменных `var books_cat = 10;` и `var ages = 12;` , чтобы было как-то так :

`query_posts('cat=$books_cat, cat=$ages');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вариантов в целом немного - это делается с помощью Get/Post запроса (Ajax). Каким именно способом - решать вам. Ведь для того, чтобы js переменная оказалась в php её придется в том или ином виде отправить на сервер. В гугле много ответов на подобный сценарий [тык](https://www.google.by/search?q=php%20%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20js&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=YrxjWObKFszi8Af76LZw). Возможно, есть особый прием именно для cms, но в общем случае общение JS->PHP делается именно так.