# Передача номера категории в query_post

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, веб-программирование

Сайт работает на wordpress. Есть цикл

```
<div class="book">
<div class="previev">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
</div>
<div class="book_tag">
<?php the_tags('', ' > '); ?>
</div>

<div class="book_description">
<div class="post_cat">
<?php the_category('', 'single'); ?>
</div>

<a class="book_title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?>   
</a>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Нужно реализовать возможность передачи номера категории из js - сюда

query_posts('cat=10, cat=здесь должна быть цифра полученная из js');

Есть проблема, указав сюда переменную из php нельзя.

```
$ten = 10;
$seven = 8; 
query_posts('cat=$ten, cat=$seven');
```

- не работает.

Возможно есть другой wordpress цикл который выводит посты определенной категории по id и при этом позволяет указывать id в виде переменной?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [вывод конкретных категорий wordpress](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608880/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-wordpress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное просто скобки не те.
Если хочешь использовать переменные в строках - нужно кавычки двойные ставить:

```
$ten = 10;
$seven = 7;
query_posts("cat=$ten, cat=$seven");
```

Еще красивее так (можно и функции внутрь фигурных скобок вставлять)

```
$ten = 10;
$seven = -10;    
query_posts("cat={$ten}, cat={abs($seven)}");
```

Comment: Помогло! Осталось только передать значение переменной js в php ajax'ом

Comment: Легче легкого если есть jquery. `$.get('/test.php', {count: 7}, function(response){
console.log('сервер ответил', response)
 })`

Comment: На сервере в скрипте test.php: `echo 'Привет, нам тут цифру ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["count"]) . 'передали';`

Comment: сорян, с вордпрессом никогда не сталкивался, но он работает точно также как и любой другой php сайт )

Comment: видимо есть у него какая-то особенность.

Comment: так а что именно не получилось то? var_dump($_GET) - пришло на сервер сообщение то? что jquery сказал когда вводишь указанный мной код в консоль (F12)?

Comment: цифра вывелась в консоль.

Comment: Но присвоить её переменной php не удается